# EditText.getText() cannot be resolved, making a file protection app

Tags: android, file

I am making a file protection application that asks users to enter a password, this password is stored and next time to view the file they have to enter the same password.

I am able to ask users to set password, and protect the file, and I am able to ask users to enter password for viewing. the issue I have is with the input field.

The code for setting password is:

```
public static void protect(final File file, final FileListActivity mContext, final OperationCallback<Void> callback)
    {

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        final EditText input = new EditText(mContext);
        input.setHint(mContext.getString(R.string.enter_new_name));
        input.setSingleLine();
        layout.addView(input);

        final EditText confirm = new EditText(mContext);
        confirm.setHint(mContext.getString(R.string.confirm_new_name));
        confirm.setSingleLine();
        layout.addView(confirm);

        new Builder(mContext)
        .setTitle(mContext.getString(R.string.rename_dialog_title, file.getName()))
        .setView(layout)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                String newName = confirm.getText().toString();
                String password=input.getText().toString();


            try
            {
                //File parentFolder = file.getParentFile();
                if (newName.equals(input.getText().toString())){
                    pass=newName;
                    pe=true;
                    filename=file.getName();
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"password match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
                }
                else if (!newName.equals(password)) {
                    pe=false;
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"password doesnot match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                else
                {
                    if(callback!=null)
                    {
                        callback.onFailure(new Exception());
                    }
                    if(mContext!=null)
                    new Builder(mContext)
                    .setTitle(mContext.getString(R.string.error))
                    .setMessage(mContext.getString(R.string.rename_failed, file.getName()))
                    .show();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                if(callback!=null)
                {
                    callback.onFailure(e);
                }

                Log.e(TAG, "Error occured while renaming path", e);

                if(mContext!=null)
                new Builder(mContext)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setTitle(mContext.getString(R.string.error))
                .setMessage(mContext.getString(R.string.rename_failed, file.getName()))
                .show();
            }
          }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

              dialog.dismiss();
          }
        })
        .show();
}
```

The code for asking users for the password to view the file is:

```
private void checkpass(final File file,FileListActivity mContext){


        if(FileActionsHelper.pe==true && file.getName().equals(FileActionsHelper.filename)){
            final EditText input = new EditText(FileListActivity.this);
            input.setHint(mContext.getString(R.string.password_add));
            input.setSingleLine();
            new Builder( mContext)
            .setTitle(mContext.getString(R.string.rename_dialog_title, file.getName()))
            .setView(input)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                try
                {
                    if ((FileActionsHelper.pass).equals("1")){

                    openFile(file);
                        Toast.makeText( FileListActivity.this,"password matched", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
                    }
                    else if (!(FileActionsHelper.pass).equals("1")) {

                        Toast.makeText( FileListActivity.this,"you entered wrong password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                    else if (FileActionsHelper.pe!=true){
                        openFile(file);

                    }


            }

                catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error occured while renaming path", e);
                }
            }


        }).setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

              dialog.dismiss();
          }
        })
        .show();


}
}

the code for opening of file is:



    void openFile(File file) {
            //if(FileActionsHelper.pe==true && file.getName().equals(FileActionsHelper.filename)){


            checkpass(file,FileListActivity.this);
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            String type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(
                    MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(uri.toString()));
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, type == null ? "*/*" : type);
            startActivity((Intent.createChooser(intent,getString(R.string.open_using))));}
            //else {


        //  }
        //}
```

The error i am getting is in the function check pass, at `input.getText.toString();` it says `getText` cannot be resolved into a type or field.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: I've edited your question and changed the title a bit, as a relevant title increases your chance of getting an answer. In your code, are you using `getText()` or `getText` ?

Comment: i am using getText()

Comment: Are you doing this in a normal Activity ? Try using `Context mContext` instead of `FileListActivity mContext` In your method declaration. Also try _not_ having it as `final`.